# In Date.toLocaleString(), locale "ja-JP" can't show hour in 2-digit format?

Tags: javascript, datetime

This behavior doesn't occur when using locale "en-US".

Also, whether hour is set to "2-digit" or "numeric",
the output remains the same for both "ja-JP" and "en-US" locales.

Is this a bug? Is there a workaround to show the hour in 2-digits in this format?

> yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss

```js
function showDate() {
    var date = new Date('2019-05-22T00:37:36.37Z');

    var options = { year: 'numeric', day: '2-digit', month: '2-digit', 
                    hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit',
                    hour12: false };

    document.querySelector("#ja-jp").innerHTML = date.toLocaleString('ja-JP', options);
    document.querySelector("#en-us").innerHTML = date.toLocaleString('en-US', options);
}
window.onload = showDate;
```

```html
<div id="ja-jp"></div>
<div id="en-us"></div>
```

Comment: If a bug, would be weird that Chrome, Firefox, Safari (IE? not tested) all get the same result. However, [reading the specs](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0/#FormatDateTime), I can't seem to find how they can achieve this result when `Intl.NumberFormat('ja-JP', {minimumIntegerDigits: 2, useGrouping: false}).format(9)` returns `"09"`...

Comment: The actual value of the `hour` option seems to be irrelevant when the locale is `ja-JP`. It is permanently numeric. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this can help you, but have a look at http://phrogz.net/JS/FormatDateTime_JS.txt

A very nice way to format dates in JS.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I'll take note of this but I'm still hoping I'm just missing something in my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really like this workaround so I'm not going to accept this as the answer.
But since it works, I'm just gonna put it here.

```
function formatDate(date) {
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    var month = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    var day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);

    var hour = ("0" + date.getHours()).slice(-2);
    var minute = ("0" + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
    var second = ("0" + date.getSeconds()).slice(-2);

    return year + "/" + month + "/" + day + " " + hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second;
}
```

Reference [link](https://usefulangle.com/post/126/javascript-display-date-time).